# Excel Interop Error Message on For Each loop

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm trying to recreate an excel macro I had in c#, but am running into an error that I can't solve. Basically the program takes the raw data from the first worksheet, it is supposed to filter it based on column AA and then copy that range and paste it into it's own new worksheet. I keep getting this error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)' on the line right after the for each statement, any ideas?

```
            foreach (var facility in machine)
            {
                firstWS.Range["A1:I" + lastRow2].AutoFilter(3, machine, XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                Excel.Range visibleCells = firstWS.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);
                firstWS.AutoFilter.Range.Copy();
                Excel.Worksheet newWS = xlApp2.Worksheets.Add(After: xlWorkbook2.Sheets[xlWorkbook2.Sheets.Count]);
                newWS.AutoFilterMode = false;
                newWS.Paste();

            }
```

Below is the entire code if that helps, sorry it is a little messy, I'm very new to C#:

````
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp2;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook2;
            Excel.Worksheet ws2;
            Excel.Worksheet newSheetName;
            Excel.Range rng3;
            Excel.Range rng4;

            long lastRow2;
            long fullRow;
            xlApp2 = new Excel.Application();

            //open workbook
            xlWorkbook2 = xlApp2.Workbooks.Open(fileExcel, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            //system hides the workbook from the user while the code runs
            xlApp2.Visible = true;
           
            //declare the first worksheet "Report" as firstWS
            Worksheet firstWS = xlWorkbook2.Worksheets["Report"];
            //Sort the worksheet by column C **work in progress**
            fullRow = firstWS.Rows.Count;
            lastRow2 = firstWS.Cells[fullRow, "I"].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
            rng3 = firstWS.Range["A1:I" + lastRow2];
            rng3.Sort(rng3.Columns[3], XlSortOrder.xlAscending);
            
            //firstWS.Columns["C"].Sort("C", XlSortOrder.xlAscending);
            //Delete columns K:N, F:I and then update the column names of F1:I1
            firstWS.Range["K:N"].Delete(XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftToLeft);
            firstWS.Range["F:I"].Delete(XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftToLeft);
            firstWS.Range["F1"].Value = "Current Qty";
            firstWS.Range["G1"].Value = "NDC";
            firstWS.Range["H1"].Value = "Pkg Sz of Comm. Containers";
            firstWS.Range["I1"].Value = "Number of Full Comm. Containers";
            //Sets the filter for Column C to use to name the different worksheets
            firstWS.Columns[3].AdvancedFilter(XlFilterAction.xlFilterCopy, Type.Missing, CopyToRange: firstWS.Range["AA1"],Unique: true);
            firstWS.Range["A1:I" + lastRow2].Copy();
            Worksheet newerWSCopy = xlWorkbook2.Worksheets.Add();
            newerWSCopy.Name = "Reporting";
            rng4 = newerWSCopy.Range["A1"];
            rng4.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteValues);
            //machine = firstWS.Range["AA2", firstWS.Cells[fullRow, "AA"].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp)];

            Excel.Range machine = firstWS.Range["AA2", firstWS.Cells[firstWS.Rows.Count, "AA"].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp)];
            

            

            foreach (var facility in machine)
            {
                firstWS.Range["A1:I" + lastRow2].AutoFilter(3, machine, XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                Excel.Range visibleCells = firstWS.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);
                firstWS.AutoFilter.Range.Copy();
                Excel.Worksheet newWS = xlApp2.Worksheets.Add(After: xlWorkbook2.Sheets[xlWorkbook2.Sheets.Count]);
                newWS.AutoFilterMode = false;
                newWS.Paste();

            }```



I've tried reworking this line but keep getting this same error.
````

Comment: Sorry, meant to also include this is the error message in the output log: Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out, I needed to change the foreach variable and the autofilter criteria.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).